# Give an example of a matrix A such that im(A) is the plane with the normal vector [1,3,2] in $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example of a matrix A such that im(A) is the plane with the normal vector \begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\2\end{bmatrix} in $R^3$

How would I go about doing this question. The solution manual doesn't make sense, and lists the vectors as

[
    \begin{bmatrix}-2&-3\\0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
]

Answer (score 2):

The image of $A$ is the span of the columns of $A$.  A plane is spanned by two independent vectors.  So you need $A$ to have two columns; each column must be a vector in the plane, and therefore perpendicular to the given vector.  You can find two such vectors by trial and error.

Does the given solution make more sense now?

It is also worth noting that there are many possible answers for $A$.  There are many ways to choose two independent vectors in the plane perpendicular to the given vector; and you can even add further columns, as long as every column is still perpendicular to the given vector.  For example, here are two more answers:
$$\pmatrix{1&2\cr3&4\cr-5&-7}\ ,\qquad
  \pmatrix{4&-1&9\cr-3&5&1\cr\frac52&-7&-6\cr}\ .$$

Comment: makes sense. thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The points on the desired plane $P$ are described by the equation
$$
x+3\,y+2\,z=0
$$
Thus $(x,y,z)$ is on $P$ if and only if
\begin{align*}
(x,y,z)
&=(-3\,y-2\,z,y,z)\\
&= (-3,1,0)\,y+(-2,0,1)\,z
\end{align*}
That is, 
$$
P=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
-3\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
-2\\0\\1
\end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$
This proves that $P$ is the image of the linear map $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^3$ defined by the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-3&-2\\1&0\\ 0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$